# Why is this ZSH function not setting the variables, and outputting a git command instead?

Tags: git, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Trying to create a custom `git` function to check to see how far ahead/behind a branch is to another branch. The logic works, if I copy/paste line by line in a terminal it works.

However, putting this in my `.zshrc` does not:

```
function gba() {
  branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
  counts_str="$(git rev-list --left-right --count origin/dev...$branch)"
  counts=(${(ps:\t:)${counts_str}})
  behind=$counts[1]
  ahead=$counts[2]

  echo "$branch behind $behind commits, ahead $ahead commits"
}
```

Also, if I run in in a script, adding `#!/bin/zsh` and executing with `zsh gba.sh` it works.

When I have it in my `.zshrc` (and make sure I open a new terminal window) it outputs all the `git` remote branches.

Any ideas? I'd like to have it in my `.zshrc` so I don't have a separate script file, and would like to run it with just `gba` or similar like an alias.

### Findings

Based on suggestions, I've run a few things to see how `gba` is interpreted when defined directly in my `.zshrc`:

```
15:33:41 ~$ which gba
gba: aliased to git branch -a
15:33:46 ~$ declare -f gba
gba () {
  branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
  counts_str="$(git rev-list --left-right --count origin/dev...$branch)"
  counts=(${(ps:\t:)${counts_str}})
  behind=$counts[1]
  ahead=$counts[2]
  echo "$branch behind $behind commits, ahead $ahead commits"
}
15:34:04 ~$ (set -x; gba)
+-zsh:3> git branch -a
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

### Solution

Turns out I didn't realize I had the `git` `oh-my-zsh` plugin enabled in `.zshrc` from the line:

```
plugins=(git)
```

This loads in a ton of aliases (which I was aware of, but I thought I had it disabled.) So commenting that line makes my `gba` function work perfectly. The `oh-my-zsh` `git` aliases are nice, but I would rather learn the full commands for things as I go, then later manually add aliases if I want to.

Comment: Note for now, I'm creating a `gba.sh` script and will make an alias in my `.zshrc`

Comment: As an aside, all-caps variable names aren't ideal. POSIX specifies all-caps names for shell-builtin variables and environment variables with meaning to the system, reserving names with at least one character for application use -- meaning that if you were using lowercase names, you wouldn't risk of overwriting something important by mistake. (Setting a shell variable with a name that matches an environment variable automatically overwrites the latter, so environment-variable naming conventions necessarily also apply to shell variables insofar as collision avoidance is concerned).

Comment: `BRANCH="$\`git ...\`"` looks like a typo. `BRANCH=$(git ...)` instead.

Comment: Back on topic -- can you figure out reproduction steps and include them in the question?

Comment: (...and to add to Chepner's point -- `$()` is strongly preferred over backticks -- behavior within them is less confusing if writing code with literal backslashes, or if trying to nest multiple command substitutions).

Comment: ...btw, consider declaring your locals -- right now, every time your function runs it's leaving a whole bunch of global variables behind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks I'll switch to lowercase vars in my scripts, makes sense, was always used to changing system variables, figured it was just a convention. And yes the `"$`...`` was a typo (had switched from `"${"` to `"`...`"`

Comment: so, if I can suggest something -- define the script in your `.zshrc`; source it or open a new shell window; then provide the output of both `declare -f gba` and `(set -x; gba)`.

Comment: the output of `declare -f gba` will tell us how the shell interpreted the definition (if that differs from the source code you intended to enter in any way) and the `set -x` log will show how the code is actually executing in practice.

Comment: (BTW, you'll note that output from `declare -f gba` uses POSIX-compliant function definition syntax, which *doesn't* use the `function` keyword. Personally, I tend to suggest getting in the habit of using the more portable syntax yourself -- no point to getting into habits that'll break whenever you need to write code for a different shell).

Comment: okay, I'll define the script and run `declare` and `set` like you've suggested. Also I've made those fixes lowercase vars, $() etc, thanks.

Comment: Ahh, so you've got an alias that's masking your function!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy should I perhaps do the same with `gba.sh` and see how it's `declare` and `set` results?

Comment: `unalias gba` should take care of things.

Comment: ...basically, the alias is rewriting your command line in such a way that your function is never getting called.

Comment: nice find @CharlesDuffy how did you see it was an already existing alias from that output?

Comment: Given in the output of `which gba` -- which I looked at because the `set -x` output was showing that it was running a command that didn't exist anywhere in the function. (BTW, only in zsh is `which` the right tool for the job; in bash, it would be `type gba`, since `which` is an external tool with no access to shell builtins/state).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy make an answer and I'll accept it, that was the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is right here:

```
15:33:41 ~$ which gba
gba: aliased to git branch -a
```

...there's an alias also named `gba`, so your function isn't being invoked. Run `unalias gba` to remove it.

---

Incidentally, one big clue was the `set -x` output:

```
15:34:04 ~$ (set -x; gba)
+-zsh:3> git branch -a
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

...since `git branch -a` isn't present anywhere in the function, this definition had to be coming from somewhere else.